# How to write a String to POJO converter in my spring boot rest service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, converters

I have a JavaFX client that consumes a Rest Service implemented in Spring Boot v2.0.0, while developping I did created a controller where it have a list of POJO as a request parameter in a Post request so I can add a set of entities object in one call

Here is what I have done till now

My controller :

```
@PostMapping
private ServerResponse creatAllCompDatas(
        @RequestParam final List<ComponentDataForm> componentDataFormValues
) {

    if (isSessionValid()) {
        List<Long> datasIds = new ArrayList();
        componentDataFormValues.stream().forEach(formValue -> {
            MNG_COMPOSANT_DATA mng_composant_data = new MNG_COMPOSANT_DATA();

            mng_composant_data.setCmp_attr_code(formValue.getAttCode());
            mng_composant_data.setCmp_attr_label(formValue.getAttTitle());
            mng_composant_data.setCmp_attr_value(formValue.getAttVal());

            datasIds.add(mng_composant_data.getId());
        });

        initSuccessResponse(datasIds);
        return serverResponse;
    }
    initFailLoginResponse();
    return serverResponse;
}
```

My ComponentDataForm POJO (DTO in this case)

```
@Component
public class ComponentDataForm {
        @JsonProperty("attCode")
        private String attCode;
        @JsonProperty("attTitle")
        private String attTitle;
        @JsonProperty("attVal")
        private String attVal;

        public ComponentDataForm() {
        }

        public String getAttCode() {
            return attCode;
        }

        public void setAttCode(String attCode) {
            this.attCode = attCode;
        }

        public String getAttTitle() {
            return attTitle;
        }

        public void setAttTitle(String attTitle) {
            this.attTitle = attTitle;
        }

        public String getAttVal() {
            return attVal;
        }

        public void setAttVal(String attVal) {
            this.attVal = attVal;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.attCode);
            hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.attTitle);
            hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.attVal);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final ComponentDataForm other = (ComponentDataForm) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.attCode, other.attCode)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.attTitle, other.attTitle)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(this.attVal, other.attVal)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ComponentDataForm{" + "attCode=" + attCode + ", attTitle=" + attTitle + ", attVal=" + attVal + '}';
        }

        public ComponentDataForm(String attCode, String attTitle, String attVal) {
            this.attCode = attCode;
            this.attTitle = attTitle;
            this.attVal = attVal;
        }


    }
```

By this I resumed my backend

Now I will provide you with my frontend Javafx :

```
@FXML
private void doCommit(ActionEvent event) throws UnirestException{

   if(validate()){
       final ObservableList<AppDataAttTDO> items = tableAtributes.getItems();
       final List<ComponentDataForm> componentDataFormValues = new ArrayList();
       items.stream().forEach(item -> {
           final ComponentDataForm requestItem = new ComponentDataForm();
           requestItem.setAttCode(item.getAttCode());
           requestItem.setAttTitle(item.getAttTitle());
           requestItem.setAttVal(item.getAttValue());

           componentDataFormValues.add(requestItem);
       });
       HttpResponse<String> asString = Unirest.post(APPLICATION_DATA_SERVICE_URL)
               .queryString("componentDataFormValues", componentDataFormValues)
               .asString();
       System.out.println(asString.getStatus());
       System.out.println(asString.getBody());
   }

}
```

When I do comit the request from my client to my server the server throws the following exception

> 2018-05-17 14:47:24.970  WARN 3660 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.easyData.pos.easyPos.rest.contoller.application.ComponentDataForm': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>
> 2018-05-17 14:47:24.970  WARN 3660 --- [nio-8443-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.List'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.easyData.pos.easyPos.rest.contoller.application.ComponentDataForm': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

After 1 day of research I do undestand that I need to create a converter which will parse the received request parameter to to my POJO by extending the `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;` interface to create a String,ComponentDataForm converter

But here I m stuck I donc know how to write this converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was Lost Until I did used some of my brain and did come with an idea

My pojo is a DTO that is shared between the backend and the frontend so knowing that I dont know how to convert I did say why not delegating this process to some mechanisme

Here comes jackson api

I did an override on the toString dto's method to write a json String of the current pojo and in the converter all I had is to use an `ObjectMapper` to read this json a parse it to my pojo (DTO Object)

Here is My implmentation

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ApplicationFormAddController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

for my converter

```
public class AppDataFormConverter implements Converter<String, ComponentDataForm>{

@Override
public ComponentDataForm convert(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
          return objectMapper.readValue(s, ComponentDataForm.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AppDataFormConverter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    System.out.println("handled here");
    return new ComponentDataForm();
    }

}
```

and the converter registration process

```
@Configuration
public class ConvertersConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new AppDataFormConverter());
    super.addFormatters(registry); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```